# Adding a click event to an element on "body" causing memory Leak in IE8

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-8, jquery-click-event

while working on my project we are facing a memory leak in IE8 and as I don't have much clue about where this was happening I did some trials and found that the leak was happening when ever I include this piece of code

```
$("body").off().on('#CancelTransfer',"click", function (e) { });
```

I am unsure about why this was giving an issue but when i change it to something like

```
$('#CancelTransfer').click(function(e){});
```

the memory doesn't increase, in former case memory usage of iexplorer increases gradually to a point where it is 1.7gb before crashes.

My question is why is this happening, all I am doing here is adding an event in a different way.

One more thing to note here is I am indeed using similar way of event calling on an other class which does not seem to give any issue

```
$("body").off().on(".subMenu", "click", function (e) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("subMenu", $(this).attr('data-submenu')); //need to remove all dependentcases
    });
```

I am really new to the concept of memory leaks and if anyone could clarify to me why this is happening and suggest a workaround would be really great.

Thanks.

EDIT: Just to clear this up, in the last case where I am adding the click event to ".SubMenu" it did not give any memory leak because there was no element with that class. But if suppose the element was present then it was giving issue in the later case too.

Comment: Users who are still on IE8 are probably used to it that nothing works, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to use `$("body").off()`?!

Comment: @A.Wolff using off() to close the existing event and register it anew again, thought it would be best to use it. anything wrong with it?

Comment: @PervyNinja I don't think it can cause a memory leak but with IE8, who knows... That's said, still no sure why you need to unbind any previous event and btw, if you want just unbind `click` event, then use `.off('click')`

Answer (score 0):

Use 
$('body').on('click' , function(){});